# Free fall - equation - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, free-fall

I have a very simple question:
I want to derive the distance an object is falling in free fall. I know there are several derivations regarding this on the web. However, I tried a different approach and the results don't match. So, I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.
Here is my approach: 
As an object falls its potential energy gets converted into kinetic energy, so:

mgh = mv²/2

(from this also follows: v = sqrt(2gh), which matches with what one finds from other derivations)

h = v²/2g

Now I insert for v = h/t

h = h²/2gt²

h= 2gt²

Now, as one can easily check the correct equation is h = gt²/2. Any ideas where my mistake is?

Comment: In $h=v^2/2g$, $v$ is the final speed. In $v=h/t$, $v$ is the average speed. So the replacement is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming free fall in vacuum, the initial equation relates the *maximum* (initial) height to the velocity *on impact* with the ground.

The equation is not true of the instantaneous height/velocity at all points in the trajectory.

Comment: >The equation is not true of the instantaneous height/velocity at all points in the trajectory....the transfer of  K.E.  To  P.E. is true for all instants in the path  only the  v and h  will have  different value.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I insert for v = h/t

I think the above statement is  good for uniform  motion but not correct for accelerated motion...

v  at any time t  is

**v=  u + g.t**  , where **u** is velocity at  **t=0**

as after each second   the velocity  increases by the acceleration.

and insert  v^2 = g^2 t^2  in your  equation

**h =  v^2/(2.g) = g^2 .t^2 /(2.g) = (1/2) .g. t^2**

and  one gets the correct expression...

*distance travelled = initial vel. .time + (1/2) acceleration . (time)^2*

in your case  Initial  Velocity =0

Answer (score 0):

Taking down as positive the velocity time graph of an object starting from rest looks like this.

[image]

The area under a velocity against time graph is the displacement which is $h$ in this case.

> Now I insert for v = h/t

$h = \frac 12 vt \Rightarrow v = \frac{2h}{t}$

Your equation $v = \frac ht$ gives the average velocity which is half the final velocity whereas in your equation

> $mgh = mv²/2$

the velocity $v$  is the final velocity.